# react-native-realm pattern matching causes invalid predicate

Tags: react-native, realm

I have this line of code:

```
realm.objects('Users').filtered("profile LIKE '%athletic%'")
```

and I tried this line of code:

```
realm.objects('Users').filtered("profile LIKE '*athletic*'")
```

It gave the error `profile LIKE '%athletic%':1:0: Invalid predicate` when running the program.  I am unable to find documentation for pattern matching in react-native-realm.  How do I find records that return users who have profiles with the string athletic in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that kind of query, you can use `CONTAINS`

```
realm.objects('Users').filtered("profile CONTAINS 'athletic'")
```

See more on the query language used in Realm-JS [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/blob/7d6817971d17bf5d6e08c39433c053669e4850ed/docs/tutorials/query-language.md)

Comment: "profile CONTAINS 'athletic'" worked but "profile LIKE '*athletic*'" still gave the invalid predicate error.  Thanks!

Comment: Hm, I didn't realize Realm-JS is so behind... I thought LIKE would be support. Ah well, contains works

Comment: @EpicPandaForce not working using = or ==

realm.objects('TRACKS').filtered('trackId =' + this.state.trackId);